# async and await in functions flutter dart

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show a loading dialog and after some execution closing it.
Code is not executing asynchronously just after first line execution is jumping to last last. How I can make this function async,await

```
     Load().showloader(context);// simple showdialog
      //
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phnNo,
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential a) async {
          print('complete');
        },
        timeout: Duration(milliseconds: 30000),
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: (ver, code) {
          print(ver);
          verificationid = ver;
          Navigation().basicNavigation(
            Otpscreen(
              phnNo: phnNo,
              verificationid: verificationid,
            ),
            context,
          );
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
      );
      //
      Load().dismissLoader(context);
      ///////////////////

      class Load {
      showloader(context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    showDialog(
      useRootNavigator: false,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: white,
          height: size.height,
          width: size.width,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  dismissLoader(context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would advise you to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please, add source code of your `Load` class

Comment: please check now

Comment: call setstate before loading and call setstate again after loading